# Facebook Open Graph Search Filter

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am searching for facebook users' posts with a keyword, everything is fine, but I want to filter the posts according to location, I can filter it out according to gender but how can I apply location filter on it? Anyone have any idea?

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon&type=post&access_token=...........

the location filter for user search is , "...&loc=12345678...."

Comment: can you tell us how you are able to filter posts by gender?!

Comment: you get the UID in the post, so you can get the public info of the profile.

Comment: Sure but how do you manage to filter the query by gender? We all know how to retrieve the gender from a user Uid but that has nothing to do with filter this query by gender..! Any working example would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Based on my tests, this is not currently possible.